# appengine-application.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After update to GAE 1.7.5, when running it give below error:

```
17/02/2013 11:27:50 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war' is not an EAR directory. File D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
17/02/2013 11:27:50 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war' is not an EAR directory. File D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
17/02/2013 11:27:50 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war' is not an EAR directory. File D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
17/02/2013 11:27:50 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war' is not an EAR directory. File D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
```

I only have `appengine-web.xml` and not `appengine-application.xml`.  So this `appengine-application.xml` is new?  I search google and GAE, that is nothing mention about `appengine-application.xml`.

Any help?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Wenbo Me too. I would like to hear whether I can ignore this or not.

Comment: Seems that you can just ignore it...I've uploaded it to GAE and it is working fine.

Comment: @Wenbo I have raised this as GAE/J issue number 8851 (File "appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml" not detected using Java dev app server), which can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8851&can=1&sort=-id%20priority%20-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log.

Comment: @Wenbo The above GAE/J issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

INFO is not an error. Please ignore.

Things that we may or may not be working may or may not leak out early by accident. Not sayin'.

Comment: And in my case they were highlighted red. How confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  It went away once I downloaded the latest Java JRE. My project was still set to use Java 6. I hope this helps. Good Luck.